# Defining correct secured channel from endpoint to server

Tags: encryption, public-key, symmetric

I'm new to cryptography and have a question regarding encryption usage.

The scenario is as follows:

I have an endpoint hardware device (CPU - ARM A7 1.2 ghz) which runs Ubuntu 14.04.
This hardware device needs to communicate with a server (CPU - Xeon family) which also runs Ubuntu 14.04.

What is the most secured way to implement on this channel?
Does only symmetric encryption is enough? or it is better to use a-symmetric for key exchange?
What else can be added to this channel? digital certificates? MAC's for integrity?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: You had a look at TLS v1.2?

Comment: Not yet, does it consists both asymmetric and symmetric encryption?

Comment: TLS v1.2 is *the* protocol for establishing a secured channel. It uses asymmetric crypto for key-exchanges, uses symmetric crypto for bulk encryption, MAC's the packets and uses certificates (or pre-shared keys) for identity verification. If you have a connection between your machines and want it secured TLS v1.2 is your way to go.

Comment: @SEJPM , many thanks for this explanation, you rock. Is there a best practice implementation guide of TLS v1.2?

Comment: Best practice for TLS deployment: Don't do it yourself. Use any of the standard libraries like [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS), [LibreSSL](http://www.libressl.org/), [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/), [GnuTLS](http://www.gnutls.org/) or [s2n](https://github.com/awslabs/s2n)